# How to set the Project.configurations property in a custom JavaExec task class in buildSrc?

Tags: java, gradle

I am writing a custom task class that extends JavaExec. The custom class lives in `buildSrc`, for which I followed [the official documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html). In the custom class, I'd like to set the classpath explicitly so that I don't have to set the same classpath over and over when I reuse this type of task. What I want to achieve is set the classpath in a way so that I don't have to configure this type of task with

```
classpath = configurations.testRuntime
```

in `build.gradle` repeatedly. That said, how can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, extending a task class isn't the right solution. Instead, your task class should be modelled after its specific purpose, and if necessary, call the `project.exec()` method internally. (`project.exec()` offers the exact same API as the `Exec` task class.) The alternative is to write a plugin that declares and configures one or more `Exec` tasks.

Note that a task class should never reach out into the project *model* (e.g. with code such as `project.configurations.testRuntime`), as that makes it totally inflexible. Instead, a task class should operate solely on its input properties. Preconfiguring these inputs and glueing things together is what plugins are for.